How can I support Android's 16KB page size in my Flutter app?
Currently my Flutter app doesn't work on devices that support 16KB page size (I checked it on the simulator). What can I do to fix this? The current version of Flutter is 3.19.4。
Error log is

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]
Error launching application on sdk gphone16k x86 64.

Environments.

Flutter : 3.19.4
Platform : Android and iOS
compileSdkVersion : 34
use firebase

I also tried updating to Flutter 3.22.1, but the same error message appeared before and after the update.
Update:
I updated Flutter to 3.24.1 and built it again, but the same error appeared. Also, when I ran the following shell script against the APK built with 3.24.1, the following result was displayed:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/page-sizes#test
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/mips/libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**16)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/armeabi-v7a/libflutter.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**16)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/armeabi-v7a/libapp.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**14)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/armeabi-v7a/libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/armeabi-v7a/libbarhopper_v3.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/armeabi-v7a/libface_detector_v2_jni.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/armeabi-v7a/libtoolChecker.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/mips64/libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**16)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86/libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86/libbarhopper_v3.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86/libface_detector_v2_jni.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86/libtoolChecker.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**16)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/arm64-v8a/libapp.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**16)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/arm64-v8a/libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**16)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/arm64-v8a/libbarhopper_v3.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/arm64-v8a/libface_detector_v2_jni.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**14)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/arm64-v8a/libtoolChecker.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/armeabi/libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**16)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86_64/libapp.so: \e[32mALIGNED\e[0m (2**16)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86_64/libpl_droidsonroids_gif.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86_64/libbarhopper_v3.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86_64/libface_detector_v2_jni.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)
./build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/target/lib/x86_64/libtoolChecker.so: \e[31mUNALIGNED\e[0m (2**12)



You might be using an outdated version, because this issue is closed already.
This counts for the main branch, while the version number may be the next.
As explained there, one can check with: readelf -Wl ./libflutter.so
It's rather 3.24.1.

thank you.
It didn't work even after updating to Flutter 3.24.1. I updated the question.
Some are marked as UNALIGNED.

Does this need to be supported by all plugins?
