I am facing problem after connecting to firebase
The error is
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\educationalapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]
Error launching application on sdk gphone16k x86 64.

Can someone help me to fix it i try
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk


Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78913494/how-can-i-support-androids-16kb-page-size-in-my-flutter-app and try the solution suggested there, and read the discussion that is linked?

I encountered an error after adding firebase_auth and increasing the minSdkto 23. Do you know how to fix it?
